# Issue with getting values of checkboxes checked in HTML form in PHP

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have a HTML form that I build using php like this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <?php
            $getW = "SELECT personID, firstName, lastName FROM person";
            $wResult = mysql_query($getW, $database);
            print("<form action='actions/editPeopleTask.php'><pre>");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($wResult))
            {
                $personID = $row[0];
                $personName = $row[1] . " " . $row[2];

                $assignedQ = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE personID = '$personID'";
                if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($assignedQ, $database)) > 0)
                {
                    print("<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='person[]' value=$personID /> $personName<br/><br/>");
                }
                else
                    print("<input type='checkbox' name='person[]' id='person' value=$personID /> $personName<br/><br/>");
            }
            print("<input type='submit'/ name='submit' value='submit'></br></pre></form>")

        ?>

</div>
```

There is a loop that runs through this each time to add these inputs to my form. The $personID is the id of the current person that I got from my database and $personName is the name of the person. The line at the top:

```
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($assignedQ, $database)) > 0)
```

is just to check if the person already existed in another table, so I can determine if their checkbox should be checked already or not.

The form works as it should, but then (when I submit) I go to another php file and try to get the results like so:

```
$personList = $_POST['person'];
echo count($personList);
```

But there is never anything in the list, no matter how many checkboxes I check.

From all the stuff online that I have seen, this should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Can we see more of your code (specifically the form tags)? I see nothing in the code provided that would cause problems. Here's an example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/65q-ry2

Comment: @showdev - It works! I checked out your phpfiddle and it made me realize that I forgot to include the method='POST' attribute in my form tags. Ahh I'm such an idiot. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem - glad you got it working! If you feel your solution would be helpful to others, consider posting it as an answer.